# Does docker machine have the overhead of executing docker on top of a virtual machine?

Tags: docker, docker-machine

It's a totally waste to use docker machine if my Linux distribution supports docker natively because I don't need to use a virtual machine to run docker. Is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's correct. `docker-machine` will help you provision Docker within a virtual guest using one of the supported hypervisors, but otherwise it's not necessary on Linux systems that have the required kernel support for Docker.